# Expecting working sample of DeviceIoControl reviewed

Tags: c#

I put the full code at the rear of this post.

I've recently answered a question, and the detail explanation is posted in

- [Physical disk size not correct (IoCtlDiskGetDriveGeometry)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15051660/physical-disk-size-not-correct-ioctldiskgetdrivegeometry)

And en passant  answer another one

- [DeviceIoControl does not set output buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192616/deviceiocontrol-does-not-set-output-buffer/15110951#15110951)

I'd like to know that if any one think there's any problem or improvement of the code.

---

code:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System;

namespace DiskManagement {
    using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;

    using LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES=IntPtr;
    using LPOVERLAPPED=IntPtr;
    using LPVOID=IntPtr;
    using HANDLE=IntPtr;

    using LARGE_INTEGER=Int64;
    using DWORD=UInt32;
    using LPCTSTR=String;

    public static partial class IoCtl /* methods */ {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
        static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(
            LPCTSTR lpFileName,
            DWORD dwDesiredAccess,
            DWORD dwShareMode,
            LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes,
            DWORD dwCreationDisposition,
            DWORD dwFlagsAndAttributes,
            HANDLE hTemplateFile
            );

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
        static extern DWORD DeviceIoControl(
            SafeFileHandle hDevice,
            DWORD dwIoControlCode,
            LPVOID lpInBuffer,
            DWORD nInBufferSize,
            LPVOID lpOutBuffer,
            int nOutBufferSize,
            ref DWORD lpBytesReturned,
            LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
            );

        static DWORD CTL_CODE(DWORD DeviceType, DWORD Function, DWORD Method, DWORD Access) {
            return (((DeviceType)<<16)|((Access)<<14)|((Function)<<2)|(Method));
        }

        public static void Execute<T>(
            ref T x,
            DWORD dwIoControlCode,
            LPCTSTR lpFileName,
            DWORD dwDesiredAccess=GENERIC_READ,
            DWORD dwShareMode=FILE_SHARE_WRITE|FILE_SHARE_READ,
            LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes=default(LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES),
            DWORD dwCreationDisposition=OPEN_EXISTING,
            DWORD dwFlagsAndAttributes=0,
            HANDLE hTemplateFile=default(IntPtr)
            ) {
            using(
                var hDevice=
                    CreateFile(
                        lpFileName,
                        dwDesiredAccess, dwShareMode,
                        lpSecurityAttributes,
                        dwCreationDisposition, dwFlagsAndAttributes,
                        hTemplateFile
                        )
                ) {
                if(null==hDevice||hDevice.IsInvalid)
                    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

                var nOutBufferSize=Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
                var lpOutBuffer=Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nOutBufferSize);
                var lpBytesReturned=default(DWORD);
                var NULL=IntPtr.Zero;

                var result=
                    DeviceIoControl(
                        hDevice, dwIoControlCode,
                        NULL, 0,
                        lpOutBuffer, nOutBufferSize,
                        ref lpBytesReturned, NULL
                        );

                if(0==result)
                    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

                x=(T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lpOutBuffer, typeof(T));
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(lpOutBuffer);
            }
        }
    }

    public enum MEDIA_TYPE: int {
        Unknown=0,
        F5_1Pt2_512=1,
        F3_1Pt44_512=2,
        F3_2Pt88_512=3,
        F3_20Pt8_512=4,
        F3_720_512=5,
        F5_360_512=6,
        F5_320_512=7,
        F5_320_1024=8,
        F5_180_512=9,
        F5_160_512=10,
        RemovableMedia=11,
        FixedMedia=12,
        F3_120M_512=13,
        F3_640_512=14,
        F5_640_512=15,
        F5_720_512=16,
        F3_1Pt2_512=17,
        F3_1Pt23_1024=18,
        F5_1Pt23_1024=19,
        F3_128Mb_512=20,
        F3_230Mb_512=21,
        F8_256_128=22,
        F3_200Mb_512=23,
        F3_240M_512=24,
        F3_32M_512=25
    }

    partial class DiskGeometry /* structures */ {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct DISK_GEOMETRY {
            internal LARGE_INTEGER Cylinders;
            internal MEDIA_TYPE MediaType;
            internal DWORD TracksPerCylinder;
            internal DWORD SectorsPerTrack;
            internal DWORD BytesPerSector;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct DISK_GEOMETRY_EX {
            internal DISK_GEOMETRY Geometry;
            internal LARGE_INTEGER DiskSize;

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=1)]
            internal byte[] Data;
        }
    }

    partial class DiskGeometry /* properties and fields */ {
        public MEDIA_TYPE MediaType {
            get {
                return m_Geometry.MediaType;
            }
        }

        public String MediaTypeName {
            get {
                return Enum.GetName(typeof(MEDIA_TYPE), this.MediaType);
            }
        }

        public override long Cylinder {
            get {
                return m_Geometry.Cylinders;
            }
        }

        public override uint Head {
            get {
                return m_Geometry.TracksPerCylinder;
            }
        }

        public override uint Sector {
            get {
                return m_Geometry.SectorsPerTrack;
            }
        }

        public DWORD BytesPerSector {
            get {
                return m_Geometry.BytesPerSector;
            }
        }

        public long DiskSize {
            get {
                return m_DiskSize;
            }
        }

        public long MaximumLinearAddress {
            get {
                return m_MaximumLinearAddress;
            }
        }

        public CubicAddress MaximumCubicAddress {
            get {
                return m_MaximumCubicAddress;
            }
        }

        public DWORD BytesPerCylinder {
            get {
                return m_BytesPerCylinder;
            }
        }

        CubicAddress m_MaximumCubicAddress;
        long m_MaximumLinearAddress;
        DWORD m_BytesPerCylinder;
        LARGE_INTEGER m_DiskSize;
        DISK_GEOMETRY m_Geometry;
    }
}

namespace DiskManagement {
    using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;

    using LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES=IntPtr;
    using LPOVERLAPPED=IntPtr;
    using LPVOID=IntPtr;
    using HANDLE=IntPtr;

    using LARGE_INTEGER=Int64;
    using DWORD=UInt32;
    using LPCTSTR=String;

    partial class IoCtl /* constants */ {
        public const DWORD
            DISK_BASE=0x00000007,
            METHOD_BUFFERED=0,
            FILE_ANY_ACCESS=0;

        public const DWORD
            GENERIC_READ=0x80000000,
            FILE_SHARE_WRITE=0x2,
            FILE_SHARE_READ=0x1,
            OPEN_EXISTING=0x3;

        public static readonly DWORD DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY_EX=
            IoCtl.CTL_CODE(DISK_BASE, 0x0028, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_ANY_ACCESS);

        public static readonly DWORD DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY=
            IoCtl.CTL_CODE(DISK_BASE, 0, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_ANY_ACCESS);
    }

    public partial class CubicAddress {
        public static CubicAddress Transform(long linearAddress, CubicAddress geometry) {
            var cubicAddress=new CubicAddress();
            var sectorsPerCylinder=geometry.Sector*geometry.Head;
            long remainder;
            cubicAddress.Cylinder=Math.DivRem(linearAddress, sectorsPerCylinder, out remainder);
            cubicAddress.Head=(uint)Math.DivRem(remainder, geometry.Sector, out remainder);
            cubicAddress.Sector=1+(uint)remainder;
            return cubicAddress;
        }

        public virtual long Cylinder {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public virtual uint Head {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public virtual uint Sector {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    public partial class DiskGeometry: CubicAddress {
        internal static void ThrowIfDiskSizeOutOfIntegrity(long remainder) {
            if(0!=remainder) {
                var message="DiskSize is not an integral multiple of a sector size";
                throw new ArithmeticException(message);
            }
        }

        public static DiskGeometry FromDevice(String deviceName) {
            return new DiskGeometry(deviceName);
        }

        DiskGeometry(String deviceName) {
            var x=new DISK_GEOMETRY_EX();
            IoCtl.Execute(ref x, IoCtl.DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY_EX, deviceName);
            m_DiskSize=x.DiskSize;
            m_Geometry=x.Geometry;

            long remainder;
            m_MaximumLinearAddress=Math.DivRem(DiskSize, BytesPerSector, out remainder)-1;
            ThrowIfDiskSizeOutOfIntegrity(remainder);

            m_BytesPerCylinder=BytesPerSector*Sector*Head;
            m_MaximumCubicAddress=DiskGeometry.Transform(m_MaximumLinearAddress, this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like what you have. It is much cleaner than what I did. I'm usually not a fan of recreating C++ names match in C# (since they are different languages) but it makes sense in this application.

Comment: Thank you. If there is anything can be improved or corrected, post an answer for me would be wonderful.

Comment: Have you run StyleCop on it and listened to its feedback? My only input is on the import statements - they should go inside of the namespace. You can then ask Visual Studio to sort and remove unused imports.

Comment: Also, you use a C++ -ism: "Yoda conditions" that are not necessary in C#, you used `var` instead of `string` and I think that built-in types should not be "vared". You also left out some braces around a one-liner if, which I prefer not to do. Finally there are some minor spacing issues that Visual Studio can fix for you if you delete the very last } in the class and then type it again. Your code is basically good and there exist tools that cam help you polish it better than humans can: Stylecop FxCop. The trick is using your judgement - when some StyleCop error is important and when it is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As most people in the comments suggest, it is missing a few conventions that are pretty generally accepting across all C# developers. This will mostly be looking at stylistic points as there isn't really much in wrong with the implementation.

**General notes**

Most of the bracket/whitespace-related points are enforced by Visual Studio when you close a code block (`{`).

- Types should be in `PascalCase`
- Public member names should be in `PascalCase`
- Hungarian notation (`dwDesiredAccess`) is discourages except for when naming controls in WebForms and WinForms. Go with `camelCase`.
- Your spacing is a bit off, all curly braces should be on separate lines. Methods generally should look like this:

  ```
  public void Method(Type param)
  {
      // Implementation
  }
  ```
- Generally you should have 1 (partial) class per file, this may not be applicable but wanted to mention.
- Placing a space between most symbols is encourages.
- Order your type's members like this:

  1. Variables (pref. const/static first)
  2. Constructors/Properties (either way)
  3. Methods
- Normally `ALL_CAPS`-style naming is not used in C#, sometimes it is for constants but generally not.

**Line-by-line**

Normally comments are made on the line above class definitions, you may be better putting this into an IoCtrl.Methods.cs file or something if you really want to separate the different sections of the file. I usually stay away from `partial` unless the file gets ridiculously long and can't be factored out.

```
// methods
public static partial class IoCtl {
```

While I'm not particularly a fan of it, your 'defines' at the top make sense given their application and [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of the kernal32.dll assembly.

```
using LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES = IntPtr;
using LPOVERLAPPED = IntPtr;
using LPVOID = IntPtr;
using HANDLE = IntPtr;

using LARGE_INTEGER = Int64;
using DWORD = UInt32;
using LPCTSTR = String;
```

Structure your braces like this:

```
public static void Execute<T>(
    ref T x,
    DWORD dwIoControlCode,
    LPCTSTR lpFileName,
    DWORD dwDesiredAccess = GENERIC_READ,
    DWORD dwShareMode = FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ,
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes = default(LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES),
    DWORD dwCreationDisposition = OPEN_EXISTING,
    DWORD dwFlagsAndAttributes = 0,
    HANDLE hTemplateFile = default(IntPtr)) 
{
```

Try not to span too many lines when calling functions

```
    using (var hDevice = CreateFile(lpFileName, dwDesiredAccess, dwShareMode,
        lpSecurityAttributes, dwCreationDisposition, dwFlagsAndAttributes,
        hTemplateFile)) 
    {

        if (null == hDevice || hDevice.IsInvalid)
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

        var nOutBufferSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
        var lpOutBuffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nOutBufferSize);
        var lpBytesReturned = default(DWORD);
```

Using `IntPtr.Zero` rather than an alias (`NULL`) makes it easier to understand what the value is later on.

```
        var result = DeviceIoControl(hDevice, dwIoControlCode, IntPtr.Zero, 0,
        lpOutBuffer, nOutBufferSize, ref lpBytesReturned, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Always prefer `var == <number>` over `<number> == var`, this type of condition is affectionately known as a 'yoda condition'.

```
        if (result == 0)
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

        x = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lpOutBuffer, typeof(T));
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(lpOutBuffer);
    }
}
```

Use pascal case for all types.

```
public enum MediaType : int
{
    Unknown = 0,
    F5_1Pt2_512 = 1,
    F3_1Pt44_512 = 2,
    F3_2Pt88_512 = 3,
    F3_20Pt8_512 = 4,
    F3_720_512 = 5,
    F5_360_512 = 6,
    F5_320_512 = 7,
    F5_320_1024 = 8,
    F5_180_512 = 9,
    F5_160_512 = 10,
    RemovableMedia = 11,
    FixedMedia = 12,
    F3_120M_512 = 13,
    F3_640_512 = 14,
    F5_640_512 = 15,
    F5_720_512 = 16,
    F3_1Pt2_512 = 17,
    F3_1Pt23_1024 = 18,
    F5_1Pt23_1024 = 19,
    F3_128Mb_512 = 20,
    F3_230Mb_512 = 21,
    F8_256_128 = 22,
    F3_200Mb_512 = 23,
    F3_240M_512 = 24,
    F3_32M_512 = 25
}
```

Always specify access modifiers.

```
// Structures
internal partial class DiskGeometry
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct DISK_GEOMETRY 
    {
        internal LARGE_INTEGER Cylinders;
        internal MEDIA_TYPE MediaType;
        internal DWORD TracksPerCylinder;
        internal DWORD SectorsPerTrack;
        internal DWORD BytesPerSector;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct DISK_GEOMETRY_EX 
    {
        internal DISK_GEOMETRY Geometry;
        internal LARGE_INTEGER DiskSize;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=1)]
        internal byte[] Data;
    }
}
```

There isn't really a standard on this but I prefer to keep simple getters on a single line. Also keep variables at the top of the file and use `pascalCase`;

```
// properties and fields
partial class DiskGeometry 
{
    private CubicAddress maximumCubicAddress;
    private long maximumLinearAddress;
    private DWORD bytesPerCylinder;
    private LARGE_INTEGER diskSize;
    private DISK_GEOMETRY geometry;

    public MEDIA_TYPE MediaType
    {
        get { return geometry.MediaType; }
    }

    public String MediaTypeName
    {
        get { return Enum.GetName(typeof(MEDIA_TYPE), this.MediaType); }
    }

    public override long Cylinder
    {
        get { return geometry.Cylinders; }
    }

    public override uint Head
    {
        get { return geometry.TracksPerCylinder; }
    }

    public override uint Sector
    {
        get { return geometry.SectorsPerTrack; }
    }

    public DWORD BytesPerSector
    {
        get { return geometry.BytesPerSector; }
    }

    public long DiskSize
    {
        get { return diskSize; }
    }

    public long MaximumLinearAddress
    {
        get { return maximumLinearAddress; }
    }

    public CubicAddress MaximumCubicAddress
    {
        get { return maximumCubicAddress; }
    }

    public DWORD BytesPerCylinder
    {
        get { return bytesPerCylinder; }
    }
}
```

Don't concatenate variable declarations, one line, one variable.

```
// constants
partial class IoCtl
{
    public const DWORD DISK_BASE = 0x00000007;
    public const DWORD METHOD_BUFFERED = 0;
    public const DWORD FILE_ANY_ACCESS = 0;

    public const DWORD GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000;
    public const DWORD FILE_SHARE_WRITE = 0x2;
    public const DWORD FILE_SHARE_READ = 0x1;
    public const DWORD OPEN_EXISTING = 0x3;

    public static readonly DWORD DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY_EX =
        IoCtl.CTL_CODE(DISK_BASE, 0x0028, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_ANY_ACCESS);

    public static readonly DWORD DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY =
        IoCtl.CTL_CODE(DISK_BASE, 0, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_ANY_ACCESS);
}
```

Put properties before methods (optional), use a single line for auto-properties.

```
public partial class CubicAddress
{
    public virtual long Cylinder { get; set; }
    public virtual uint Head { get; set; }
    public virtual uint Sector { get; set; }

    public static CubicAddress Transform(long linearAddress, CubicAddress geometry) 
    {
        var cubicAddress = new CubicAddress();
        var sectorsPerCylinder = geometry.Sector * geometry.Head;
        long remainder;
        cubicAddress.Cylinder = Math.DivRem(linearAddress, sectorsPerCylinder, out remainder);
        cubicAddress.Head = (uint)Math.DivRem(remainder, geometry.Sector, out remainder);
        cubicAddress.Sector = 1 + (uint)remainder;
        return cubicAddress;
    }
}
```

Constructor(s) before methods.

```
public partial class DiskGeometry: CubicAddress 
{
    DiskGeometry(String deviceName)
    {
        var x = new DISK_GEOMETRY_EX();
        IoCtl.Execute(ref x, IoCtl.DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY_EX, deviceName);
        diskSize = x.DiskSize;
        geometry = x.Geometry;

        long remainder;
        m_MaximumLinearAddress = Math.DivRem(DiskSize, BytesPerSector, out remainder) - 1;
        ThrowIfDiskSizeOutOfIntegrity(remainder);

        mytesPerCylinder = BytesPerSector * Sector * Head;
        maximumCubicAddress = DiskGeometry.Transform(maximumLinearAddress, this);
    }

    internal static void ThrowIfDiskSizeOutOfIntegrity(long remainder) 
    {
        if (remainder != 0)
        {
            var message = "DiskSize is not an integral multiple of a sector size";
            throw new ArithmeticException(message);
        }
    }

    public static DiskGeometry FromDevice(String deviceName)
    {
        return new DiskGeometry(deviceName);
    }
}
```

Phew... Big.

I haven't changed the hungarian notations because I'm sure I would miss some and inconsistencies are no good in review :) I also didn't change the `ALL_CAPS` variables as I couldn't find where some were defined.